# How would I go about managing queues within a hashmap?

Tags: java, data-structures

I want to get access of the PetQueue and using the ID number of the pet adds the Pet object (not just the ID number) to the shortest queue available. I am unsure of to go about managing the queues, finding the shortest. Whenever I run this it always adds the pet to the same queue no matter the size.

```
   static void admitPatient(Map<Integer, Pet> readPets, HashMap<String, PetQueue> vetMap) {
        if (vetMap.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No vets are currently checked in.");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Enter the pet's id number: ");
            int petID = Integer.parseInt(keyb.nextLine());
            Pet p1 = readPets.get(petID);
            if (p1 != null) {
                PetQueue shortestQueue = null;
                Map.Entry<String, PetQueue> entry = vetMap.entrySet().iterator().next();
                //System.out.println(entry);
                int size = entry.getValue().size() +1;
                String drName = "";
                System.out.println("size" + size);
                for (Map.Entry<String, PetQueue> vetsAndQueue : vetMap.entrySet()) {
                   // System.out.println(vetsAndQueue.getValue());
//                    PetQueue  vetsAndQSize = vetsAndQueue.getValue();
                    if (vetsAndQueue.getValue().size() <= size){
                        shortestQueue = vetsAndQueue.getValue();
                        shortestQueue.enqueue(p1);
                        drName = vetsAndQueue.getKey();
                    }
                }
                vetMap.put(drName,shortestQueue);

                System.out.printf("%s will see Dr. %s\n", p1, drName);
            }else{
                    System.out.printf("No pet found with ID %d\n", petID);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: can u share Pet & PetQueue class?

Comment: It looks like maybe you enqueued the pet (`p1`) a little bit early, before   before you had actually finished finding the shortest queue.

Comment: @KevinAnderson when should I enqueue it?

Comment: _After_ the `for` loop that's finding the shortest queue, not inside it.

Answer (score 0):

The logic you use to find the shorted queue is not clear.

First, you set the search limit to be `int size = entry.getValue().size() +1;` which is the size of the first element in the iterator plus one.

Then you use the `if (vetsAndQueue.getValue().size() <= size)` to find the shortest queue. Most of the time it will just run into the same first element in the iterator and just run into the if block and the pet will be enqueued directly. That's why you end up having the pet always in the same queue.

The definition of `size` variable doesn't make sense since you have no guarantee that the first queue in the vetMap is of the smallest size.

Just as other has answered you just need to wait till you find the real shortest queue to ensue you pet element. It could look like this:

```
static void admitPatient(Map<Integer, Pet> readPets, HashMap<String, PetQueue> vetMap) {
        if (vetMap.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No vets are currently checked in.");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Enter the pet's id number: ");
            int petID = Integer.parseInt(keyb.nextLine());
            Pet p1 = readPets.get(petID);
            if (p1 != null) {
                Map.Entry<String, PetQueue> shortestQueueVet = null;
                Map.Entry<String, PetQueue> entry = vetMap.entrySet().iterator().next();
                //System.out.println(entry);
                int size = entry.getValue().size();
                String drName = "";
                System.out.println("size" + size);
                for (Map.Entry<String, PetQueue> vetsAndQueue : vetMap.entrySet()) {
                    if (vetsAndQueue.getValue().size() < size){// here keep finding shortest queue
                        size = vetsAndQueue.getValue().size();
                        shortestQueueVet = vetsAndQueue;
                    }
                }
                shortestQueueVet.getValue().enqueue(p1);
                drName = shortestQueueVet.getKey();
                //vetMap.put(drName, shortestQueue); ##you don't need to re-put the element since the key remains unchanged

                System.out.printf("%s will see Dr. %s\n", p1, drName);
            }else{
                    System.out.printf("No pet found with ID %d\n", petID);
                }
            }
        }
}
```